# change url of NSURL dynamically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a `NSURL` member in my view controller. Based on user input like which button user pressed I have to dynamically get the url string and create a `NSURL` object.

Currently each time I am creating one `NSURL` object. I know this is a memory leak. Is there any way where I can change the url string value of `NSRUL` member without deleting its memory?

I can't release `NSURL` member as the project is under `@autoreleasepool`.

---

Code snippet:

```
@interface myViewController : UIViewController <MyWebViewDelegate>
{
     NSURL* NavigationURL;

         ...
}

@implementation myViewController

...

-(IBAction) LoadURL
{
    if (self.NavigationURL)
    {
        NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:NavigationURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
        [WebView loadRequest:Request];
    }
}


- (IBAction)onHomeClick:(UIButton *)sender 
{ 
    switch (sender.tag) 
    {
        case 101: 
            {
                self.NavigationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/CommAndCoord.pdf"];        
                [self LoadURL];
            }
            break;

        case 102: 
            {
                [self stopResourcesIfAlreadyLoading];

                self.NavigationURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/PartCulture.pdf"];        

                [self LoadURL];
            }
            break;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [NSUrl URLWithString:] method instead of allocating it everytime.

just like this

```
self.NavigationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/PartCulture.pdf"];
```

Comment: this will also allocate a `NSURL` object, won't it?

Comment: No the object allocated will be autoRelease, you need not to bother about that object.

Comment: I think such autorelease objects are maintained by compiler itself, and the program does not own such objects..

Comment: Hi all, my application is ARC enabled and property is retain. Thanks for all replies. URLWithString its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If `self.NavigationURL` is a `retain` (or if you are using ARC `strong`) property, then there is not issue in doing as you are. Indeed, assigning to that property will automatically take care of memory management for you and you will have no memory leak.

If you are not using ARC and your property is a `retain` one, though, you have to beware of making your object an `autoreleased` one:

```
self.NavigationURL = [[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/CommAndCoord.pdf"] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
  -(void)LoadURL:(NSURL *)url
{
if (urlL)
{
    NSURLRequest *Request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [WebView loadRequest:Request];
}
}


- (IBAction)onHomeClick:(UIButton *)sender 
{
switch (sender.tag) 
{
    case 101: 
        {
            self.NavigationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/CommAndCoord.pdf"];        
            [self LoadURL:self.NavigationURL];
        }
        break;

    case 102: 
        {
            [self stopResourcesIfAlreadyLoading];

            self.NavigationURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://zzzqmsdb.xxxxyyyy.com/sites/pex/iPadFiles/PartCulture.pdf"];        

            [self LoadURL:self.NavigationURL];
        }
        break;
 }
```